# What memory allocation does mean

Tags: c++, allocation

Consider the following line:

```
int v[100];
```

This line allocates `100*sizeof(int)` memory bytes. But if we're looking for disassembly of this line then there is no code behind it. So does memory allocation executed with no machine instruction? I'm confused...

Comment: function prologue usually.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the context, but you are most likely talking about stack allocated memory / auto variables, like this:

```
int fn()
{
    int v[100];
    ...
}
```

If you look at the disassembly of `fn`, you should notice in the function prologue that some value is subtracted from `esp` register.

For example,

```
sub esp, 190h
```

This is the allocation you're looking for. That variable is stored on the stack, so by moving the stack pointer, `esp`, you have cleared room for it.

Comment: Or, he sees nothing because the unused variable v was deleted.

Comment: Did you mean that for every function which started to execute we have that every variable will be declare in the function prologue?

Comment: Almost. Every function has a prologue which sets up the registers and stack for its use. For more info about that, see [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). This is done *once* for every function, for the *total stack size* to allocate. So if you have two variables: `X`, of size 2 bytes, and `Y` of size 4 bytes, then you will get a single `sub esp, 6`.

Answer (score 0):

In the compiler, local variable allocations are turned into `alloca` (or "stack allocation"), which is, assuming the variable isn't "unused and completely removed", typically done by subtracting the total size needed from the stack pointer at the beginning of the function, and added back on (or otherwise restoring stack pointer) at the end of the function.

This is the "LLVM IR" (IR = Intermedia Representation) for a function like the one described above:

```
define i32 @fn() #0 {
  %v = alloca [100 x i32], align 16
  ret i32 42
}
```

In x86-64 assembler, it becomes:

```
fn:                                     # @fn
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $272, %rsp              # imm = 0x110
    movl    $42, %eax
    addq    $272, %rsp              # imm = 0x110
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

(Don't ask my why it is 272 bytes, rather than 400 - I really have no idea!)

If we enable optimisation, with -O2, it becomes:

```
fn:                                     # @fn
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $42, %eax
    retq
```

In other words, the stack allocation goes away completely.

Source code:

```
int fn()
{
    int v[100];
    return 42;
}
```